# Emplacing back class to vector of unique pointer

Tags: c++

So i have a basic sfml button class and when initializing and emplacing back variables to arrays its started throwing errors saying variables are already defined. I have two vectors one is for everything I want to be drawn and emplacing back to that works fine its just my button class. I'm sorry if this is a simple fix but I couldn't seem to find a answer online.

some code

```cpp
class button {
public:
    sf::Text text;
    sf::Sprite button;
    bool isOnButton(sf::RenderWindow& window);
    std::function<void()> ifClicked;
};

bool button::isOnButton(sf::RenderWindow& window) {
    sf::Vector2i mousePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
    sf::Vector2f mousePosF(static_cast<float>(mousePos.x), static_cast<float>(mousePos.y));
    if (button.getGlobalBounds().contains(mousePosF))
        return true;
    return false;
}

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::Drawable>> projectsDrawables;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<button>> projButtons;
sf::Texture projectBaseTex;
sf::Font font;

int main()
{
    font.loadFromFile("Assets/Graphics/times-new-roman.ttf");
    projectBaseTex.loadFromFile("Assets/Graphics/project-base.png");
    projectBaseTex.setSmooth(1);

    float loc = 1002;
    for (int i{ 0 }; i <= 5; i++) {
        button button1;
        //setup variables
        button1.button.setTexture(projectBaseTex);
        button1.button.setScale(.7, 0.05);
        button1.button.setPosition(1005, loc);
        button1.text.setFont(font);
        button1.text.setString("string");
        button1.text.setScale(1, 0.07);
        button1.text.setCharacterSize(36);
        button1.text.setPosition(1020, loc - 0.2);
        button1.text.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
        std::function<void()> temp([&] {
            //do stuff
            });
        button1.ifClicked = temp;
        projectsDrawables.emplace_back(std::make_unique<sf::Sprite>(button1.button));
        projectsDrawables.emplace_back(std::make_unique<sf::Text>(button1.text));
        projButtons.emplace_back(std::make_unique<button>(button1)); //causing error
        loc += 5;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and the errors being thrown

```
Error   C3511   'button': a call to a delegating constructor shall be the only member-initializer
Error   C2437   'text': has already been initialized
Error   C2437   'ifClicked': has already been initialized
Error   C2664   'button::button(button &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const sf::Sprite' to 'const button &'
```

errors are thrown to the last line of the file.

Thanks

Comment: For one thing, it seems that MSVC doesn't like it when a class named `button` has a member named `button`.  Try changing one of those names so they don't match.

Comment: It seems like it's trying (and failing) to use aggregate initialization to construct a new `button`.  I wonder if `button`s copy/move constructors are being implicitly deleted?

Comment: it was that i had named the sprite button. Lmao sorry that was a stupid error